# Audio library for C++ for audio plugins?

Tags: c++

I am interested in creating audio plugins like a compressor or synthesizer VST plugin for example. Though I do want to start with something as simple as a distortion plugin.

And I thought I will use C++ for it.

I am wondering which audio library would be a good fit for this case?

My inspirations are the Sonalksis compressor and Reason's Mälstrom for example.

Comment: for what platform? also, what’s your definition of “audio library”? are you looking for an interface like LADSPA? do you already know that it’s going to be a VST plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Juce](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce.php) wouldn't be a bad place to start.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look at the following resources:

- [Faust](http://faust.grame.fr/) generates C++ code (among other languages) from a high level description of dsp processes. It can output code that uses a number of audio APIs and GUI libraries.
- [Juce](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce.php). Already mentioned by @SSteve is a cross platform C++ library with a focus on audio applications.
- [STK](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/) Is a platform-independent library for sound synthesis and some DSP.
- If you can get your hands on [The Audio Programming Book](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=12283), do it!
- Another option is to describe your DSP process using [PD](http://puredata.info/) and then use [LibPD](http://libpd.cc/) to embedd it in your C++ program. I did this for a musical program that ran on an embedded device, you can see a full tutorial [here](http://elsoftwarehamuerto.org/articulos/691/puredata-beagleboard/) and the code [here](https://github.com/rvega/XookyNabox).
- [RTAudio](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtaudio/) and [RTMidi](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/) has also been very helpful for me.
- Another tricky issue regarding audio programming in C++ is inter-thread communication. I suggest you read [this](http://www.rossbencina.com/code/real-time-audio-programming-101-time-waits-for-nothing).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more that may be of interest:

1. [WDL/iPlug, Oli Larkin Edition](https://github.com/olilarkin/wdl-ol): This one has a lot of user-contributed routines and controls at the Cockos forum thread for it (a very long thread).  However, if you check the issues, you'll find that the RTAS/AAX plugins have a stability problem on PT; having to do with mutexes.  It boasts a lot of plugins made with it.
2. [RackAFX](http://www.willpirkle.com/rackafx/): This one creates a project template for you, and allows you to define GUI elements.  The DSP is all up to you in Win32 C++, but it creates some of the handling code for the GUI.  Once you have compiled yer plug, it also has a form designer of sorts, to allow you to configure and rearrange the GUI elements.  It doesn't support AAX/RTAS plugins, however.
3. [SynthEdit](http://www.synthedit.com/): Maybe not one you'd expect to find in a C++ list, but I believe it can emit C++ code - for modifying or for learning.  Yes, it does do audio plugins, and not just instruments.
4. ["A Collection of Useful C++ Classes for Digital Signal Processing"](https://github.com/vinniefalco/DSPFilters) is another that implements a lot of useful techniques, and relies on C++ templates a lot; but fair warning: Its own programmer thinks its class libraries are hard to read, and horribly designed.
5. Finally, [an STK author](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/papers/stkupdate.pdf) claims that CLAM, Csound, and SndObj are also currently supported toolkits.  Csound is its own language, but CLAM and SndObj have C++ libraries.  I don't know much about them, though.

BTW: Faust looks interesting, but its website is currently a stub with e.g. no downloads.  However, its [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/faudiostream/) page is up.  On the down side, I don't think it supports VST3 without a third-party hack.  On the up side, it is one of the few that supports Linux plugins.
FWIW: JUCE charges a lot for a commercial license for just one plugin, and more yet for a license for 2+ commercial plugins.  It would work fine if the plug is just for you, or is non-profit.  It is one of the few mentioned here that supports AAX and RTAS.